# Traversing list items using array method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the values input by the user to perform this action.

Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/7196dfyz/

This is part of the code where the elements are traversed, where I'm having trouble:

```js
var lists = $ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; ++i) {
    if (lists[i] == value) {
        $("ul").css("background-color","black");
    }
}
```

The first input should take the value in some `li`
and the second input should take the respective parent `ul` class name.

Comment: What is expected result of `if (lists[i] == value)`?

Comment: _"the first input should take the value in some li"_ do you mean the text content of an `<li>` element?

Comment: @guest271314 yes the text in any of the li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. ([Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljhzk3k4/) is an updated jsfiddle):

```
function func() {
    var key = $("#key").val();
    var value = $("#entry").val();
    var $ul = $("." + key);
    var lists = $ul.find("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; ++i) {
        console.log($(lists[i]).text(), value);
        if ($(lists[i]).text() === value) {
            $(lists[i]).css("background-color","black");
        }
    } 
}
```

You have several issues:

- `$ul.getElementsByTagName` is not a valid function. Because `$ul` at this point is a jQuery array-like object, it wont work. You'd need to do `$ul[0].getElementsByTagName`, or simply use jQuery's [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) like my example above.
- You're trying to compare `lists[i]` to value, which happens to be an HTML element. When comparing to a string, it will return `<li>Say</li>` which will never match anything you type in. Using `$(lists[i]).text()` should get you what you need.
- `$("ul").css("background-color","black");`: You were setting every `ul` to black if a match was found. I assume you only want to match the one that was matched. `$(lists[i]).css("background-color","black");` fixes this.

You can even simplify this entire function down to this:

```
function func() {
    var key = $("#key").val();
    var value = $("#entry").val();
    $("." + key).find("li").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === value;
    }).css("background-color","black");
}
```

Broken down:

- `$("." + key)`: Find the ul that has the class of `key`.
- `.find("li")` Find all list items within each unordered list found.
- `.filter(...)` For each element in this list, and return to me only the items that match my criteria: `$(this).text() === value`.
- And finally `.css("background-color","black")`: Set all the background colors to black of the list items that were returned from the `filter()` function.

Comment: Sir can u have a look at this page..i refered this page https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/looping-through-li-elements-in-ul/6049/3

Comment: You're trying to mix jQuery and javascript functions. As soon as you call `$()` anything you're dealing with an array which has jQuery extensions on it (Like `.remove()`, `.empty()`, `.append()`, `.find()`, etc...). You'd either need to filter to a specific element, or use jQuery functions on that array.

Comment: _"As soon as you call `$()` anything you're dealing with an array"_ [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) does not return an `Array`, e.g., `console.log(Array.isArray($()))`

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspoke @guest271314. It returns an array-like jQuery object, which can be accessed like an array (Through indexes). For example, `$('li')[0]` would return the first li found.

Comment: @SudhanshuSaini See my updated answer. I broke down a much simpler way to accomplish what you're looking for, and explained how it works.

Comment: @FrankerZ Actually i need if condition in it because this background color change was just for fiddle actually i have to update the value of a variable if the condition is true

Comment: So then instead of that, use the [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to loop through the found objects.

Comment: @FrankerZ can u help me out in a small problem as well? I have declared an array var arr = new Array();  i am appendind objects in it like: arr.push({value: checkboxvalue, parentid : idfound}).. here value and parentid are the data members of the object and checkboxvalue and idfound are two available variables with some value..later i am retrieving the values like : arr[i].value and arr[i].parentid. Is this a correct way?